# How can I use recursion to reverse the user input?

Tags: c++, c, recursion

I understand that this is a very trivial problem.

I am trying to write a program that will keep asking for user input as an int until the user enters 0 at which point it will terminate and print out all the digits in reverse. This is what I have so far:

```
int revList(int num)
{
    if (num != 0)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("%d\n", revList(num));
        return num;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

with my main method being:

```
int revList(int);

printf("%d", revList(1));
```

the 1 in the `revList` was chosen arbitrarily to satisfy the compiler's need for an arguement even though it's useless in the first iteration.

I understand that my code is probably inefficient and not making use of recursion properly.

The code works but has 1 problem: it prints 0 two times and then the preceding numbers. I realize where the problem stems from. It's because I have a return 0 at the end but I can't take that out because it will reach the end of a non-void function and in this manner, it returns 0 twice.

Can someone please help me fix this and give me an efficient method to address this problem?

EDIT:
example: user inputs:
1
2
3
4
5
8
0

it should output:

0
8
5
4
3
2
1

my program will output:
0
0
8
5
4
3
2
1

Comment: @chris if *you're* doing assignments like *this* in class what little faith I still had in public education has officially been shattered =P

Comment: @chris You're studying this in college? That assignment must be so simple for you.

Comment: @WhozCraig, So I went ahead a bit. The thing is that everyone is everywhere, so it's considered unfair not to start from the beginning. At least it's assumed we've done all of this in another language.

Comment: @chris yeah, we have that in America too, its the finishing clause of No Child Left Behind that no one seems to want to talk about: No Child Gets Ahead. Bummer man, but you'll hopefully start getting usable content when you reach advanced algorithms and data structures classes.

Comment: @chris what program are you in...? I am starting to think you are in the same program as me (same university) in which case this would be an extremely embarrassing situation.

Comment: @Outlier, I still have no clue who you are, but I already guessed you were in UW SE18.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reversing numbers input by user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730526/reversing-numbers-input-by-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void revList()
{
 int num = 0;
 scanf("%d", &num);

 if (num != 0)
     revList();

 printf("%d\n", num);       
}
```

I'll explain a little if you want to know the reasoning.

Firstly, the function doesn't need to return an integer because you're collecting the number from the user *and* printing it in all in one place - there's simply no need.

I'm guessing that you want 0 to be a sort of "kill command", and thus, you don't want to print it - hence why we moved the call to printf inside the if statement.

Edit:

As per you edit, you make it clear that you *do* want to print the collected 0.
Code changed accordingly.

Comment: oh wait, I've tried this before. I get error arguement type void is incomplete. this is why I tried to make a return type int. What is the problem?

Comment: Well, in your original code, you're calling revList() inside printf.  That won't work if that's what you were doing.

Without the code you had at the time, I can't help much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

```
void revList()
{
   int num = 0;
   if( std::cin >> num ) {
      if( num ) 
         revList();
      std::cout << num << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Nawaz: Nor does the OP's code. Nor is that even what he wants. Read the question.

Comment: @Outlier you asked C++ question, this is C++ way to input/output. If tags are wrong please modify it

Comment: @Nawaz why you did not put your -1 and your comments to other 2 answers? And more important, why you did not provide "good" answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
void revList()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num != 0)
    {
        revList();
    }
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

Comment: the logic works but I get error arguement type void is incomplete on line 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this avoiding the dummy argument, just pass in the first digit and if it's not zero do a reucursion until zero is reached and then print the actual digit in each recursion level when previous level returns:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int revList(int nValue)
{
    if(nValue != 0)
    {
        int nNextValue;
        scanf("%d", &nNextValue);
        revList(nNextValue);
        printf("%d", nValue);
    }
    return nValue;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int nValue;
    scanf("%d", &nValue);
    revList(nValue);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```

Comment: s/void main/int main/